# Represent video frames as volume in time

Tags: image, matlab, video, 3d, volume

I need to represent set of video frames in time as a volume i.e consider set of video frames in time, they represent a cuboid. How do I represent it as volume in Matlab? I need to manipulate this volume further using vhslice(vertical/horizontal slice operation). I am new to matlab.

Answer (score 0):

You may stack the frames into 3D (gray) or 4D (color) arrays.

For example, if you have gray-level frames you can have:

```
vol(:,:,ii) = vidFrame{ii};
```